# How to allow user to choose the file in which the pdf should be saved not in the specified folder

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, tkinter-text

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import  A4

my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("400x300")
my_w.title("PDF GENERATOR")
l1 = tk.Label(my_w,  text='Your Data', width=10 )
l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)

t1 = tk.Text(my_w,  height=12, width=45,bg='yellow')
t1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10)

b1=tk.Button(text='Generate PDF',command=lambda:gen_pdf())
b1.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=20,pady=10)

my_Style = ParagraphStyle('My Para style',fontName="Times-Roman",fontSize=16,
     alignment=0, borderWidth=2,borderColor='#FFFF00',backColor = '#F1F1F1',
                          borderPadding = (20, 20, 20),leading = 20)
width, height = A4
def gen_pdf():
    my_path = 'D:\\apps\\master.pdf'
    text=t1.get("1.0",END)
    text=text.replace('\n','<BR/>')
    p1 = Paragraph(text, my_Style)
    c = canvas.Canvas(my_path, pagesize=A4)
    p1.wrapOn(c, 300, 50)
    p1.drawOn(c, width-450,height-350)
    c.save()
    t1.delete('1.0',END)
    t1.update()
my_w.mainloop()
```

I am searching for a way where the user should choose the folder in which they want to save the pdf not in the folder decided by me.
For now I set the path to

```
my_path = 'D:\\apps\\master.pdf'
```

But I want the '''gen_def()''' command to ask the user in the way we get the option while downloading the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`asksaveasfilename()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename) to get a full path name:

```py
...
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
...

def gen_pdf():
    my_path = asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[('PDF files', '*.pdf')], defaultextension=".pdf")
    if my_path:
        text = t1.get("1.0", END)
        text = text.replace('\n', '<BR/>')
        p1 = Paragraph(text, my_Style)
        c = canvas.Canvas(my_path, pagesize=A4)
        p1.wrapOn(c, 300, 50)
        p1.drawOn(c, width-450, height-350)
        c.save()
        t1.delete('1.0', END)
```

Comment: It works fine but if I change the origin **t1** to `infodescr` where infodescr represents the scrolled textbox having text imported from excel file then It gives corrupted pdf file as an output. Kindly assist me what should I do.

Comment: @PrashantPriyadarshi This is another issue not related to this question.  You can raise a new question on that.